# Improving SQL cartesian product performance by reducing columns

Tags: sql, database, performance, cartesian-product

I have an SQL query which uses cartesian product on a large table. However, I only need one column from one of the tables. Would it actually perform better, if I selected only that one column before using the cartesian product?

So, in other words, would this:

```
SELECT A.Id, B.Id
FROM (SELECT Id FROM Table1) AS A , Table2 AS B;
```

be faster than this, given that Table1 has more columns than Id?:

```
SELECT A.Id, B.Id
FROM Table1 AS A , Table2 AS B;
```

Or does the number of columns not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most databases, the two forms would have the same execution plan.

The first could would be worse on a database (such as MySQL) that materializes subqueries.

The second should be better with indexes on the two tables . . . `table1(id)` and `table2(id)`.  The index would be used to get the value rather than the base data.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out yourself! But generally speaking having a subquery reduce the number of rows will help improve the performance. Your query should, however, be written differently:

```
select a.id aid, b.id bid from
(Select id from table1 where id=<specific_id>) a, table2 b
```

Comment: I am really sorry, I confused the words column and row (corrected it now). I meant only to reduce columns, not rows.

Comment: In that case I go with Gordon: it will probably not make any difference which form you use as you will not be outputting all the columns anyway.